# PHP: Dividing mysql result to four div

Tags: php, mysql

I have category table which include 35 category inside. I want them aline into four div with one while loop.

```
<?php 
    $count = 0;
    $cat = pullcategories();
    $catcount = mysqli_num_rows($cat);
    $percat = ceil($catcount / 4);

    $topcats = pulltopcategories($count, $percat);
    //same with pullcategories, just LIMIT $count,$per //
    while ($topcats = mysqli_fetch_object($topcats)) {
        ?>
        <div class="col3">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-dashed">
                <li>
                    <a href="">$topcats->title</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php 
        $count = $count + $percat;
        $percat = $percat * 2; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @Virb No error it seems, just asking how to do it

Comment: What are you getting with your code?

Comment: What does the code you've posted actually do? Is it an attempt to solve your issue or are you simply expecting us to refactor your code for you? You should always try your issue yourself first. Then, if you run into some specific issue when trying, you need to show us the expected result and the result you're actually getting.

Comment: Actually my code didn't give me an error, simply its wrong i think. Pretty newbie there. I just couldnt get understand that concept of dividing multiple columns my  sql data.

Comment: _"simply its wrong i think"_ - So you're asking us before you've even tested it? That's doing things backwards.

Comment: @DriererKar : Your efforts are accepted but if you fail or get some error with your code then ask for help otherwise we wont help.

Comment: @DriererKar *I want them aline into four div with one while loop.*, so in a loop you want to display 4 categories per div, right?

Comment: Not actually. As i said i have 35 data in my table. I want to distribute the data evenly across four separate div.

Answer (score 0):

```
                $count = 0;
                $cat = pullcategories();
                $catcount = mysqli_num_rows($cat);
                $percat = ceil($catcount / 4);

                $topcats = pulltopcategories($count, $percat);
```

This breaks your lists down in to 4 parts, and you would need to call "$topcats = pulltopcategories($count, $percat);" 4 times to be able to get through all the data.

I would change it to be something like this.
Assuming that "pulltopcategories($count, $percat)" uses count as the limit, and percat as the offset in the SQL this should work.

Please try and let me know - I can fix any mistakes if there are any (my PHP is a little rusty and i dont have data to try this with)

```
<?php 
                $count = 0;
                $cat = pullcategories();
                $catcount = mysqli_num_rows($cat);
                $percat = ceil($catcount / 4);

                while ($count < catcount){ /* Loop until you have finished all cats */ 
                    $topcats = pulltopcategories($count, $percat);
                    echo "<div class="col3">
                        <ul class='list-unstyled list-dashed'>";

                    while ($topcats = mysqli_fetch_object($topcats)) {
                            echo "<li>
                                <a href=''>$topcats->title</a>
                            </li>"
                    }
                    echo "</ul>
                    </div>";
                    $count = $count + $percat;
               }
?>
```